# Use Pandas to extract the values from a column based on some condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to pick a particular column from a csv file using Python's Pandas module, where I would like to fetch the `Hostname` if the column `Group` is `SJ` or `DC`.

Below is what I'm trying but it's not printing anything:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.height', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)

low_memory=False
data = pd.read_csv('splnk.csv', usecols=['Hostname', 'Group'])
for line in data:
    if 'DC' and 'SJ' in line:
        print(line)
```

The `data` variable contains the values for `Hostname` & `Group` columns as follows:

```
11960      NaN          DB-Server
11961       DC          Sap-Server
11962       SJ          comput-server
```

Note: while printing the data it stripped the data and does not print complete data.

PS: I have used the `pandas.set_option` to get the complete data on the terminal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for line in data:` doesn't iterate over row contents, it iterates over the column names.  Pandas has several good ways to filter columns by their contents.

For example, you can use [`df.Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to select rows matching one of several values:

```
print data[data['Group'].isin(['DC', 'SJ'])]['Hostname']
```

If it's important that you iterate over rows, you can use [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['Group'] == 'DC' or row['Group'] == 'SJ':
        print row['Hostname']
```

If you're just getting started with Pandas, I'd recommend trying a [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to get familiar with the basic structure.

Comment: ASGM , thnx for your answer , though `Group` has the values `DC` & `SJ` not the `Hostname`, So, if Group column has these two in line the print the corresponding column `Hostname` from the File. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sure, i'll go through the tutorial as you suggested, i'm already started looking on different sources to get the idea on pandas.

Comment: I've changed the answer accordingly.  In the future, if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the structure of your data will be clear.

Comment: ASGM, i'll take that consideration in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #You can comment numpy as it is not needed.
low_memory=False
data = pd.read_csv('splnk.csv', usecols=['Hostname', 'Group'])
hostnames = data[(data['Group']=='DC') | (data['Group']=='SJ')]['Hostname']  # corrected the `hostname` to `Hostname`
print(hostnames)
```